# reading text table into R

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I know if I copy the content of the object `block` and paste it onto a text editor (e.g., notepad), then I can read the `block.txt` file as a table in `R` like so: `read.table('block.txt', header = TRUE)`.

But is there a way to directly (without first creating a `block.txt` file) read the `block` itself in `R`?

```
block <- "Item1 Item2 Item3 
             22    52    16 
             42    33    24 
             44     8    19 
             52    47    18 
             45    43    34 
             37    32    39"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `block` as `text` argument of `read.table` :

```
read.table(text = block, header = TRUE)

#  Item1 Item2 Item3
#1    22    52    16
#2    42    33    24
#3    44     8    19
#4    52    47    18
#5    45    43    34
#6    37    32    39
```

Comment: You could also do `read.table(textconnections(block)), header= TRUE)`.  ,Also If you are in windows you dont have to paste the block anywhere. You just do `read.table(text = readClipboard(), header  = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fread`

```
library(data.table)
fread(block)
#   Item1 Item2 Item3
#1:    22    52    16
#2:    42    33    24
#3:    44     8    19
#4:    52    47    18
#5:    45    43    34
#6:    37    32    39
```